Standardization of a 1d vector in torch
I am working with torch dataset of 1d signals, and would like to standardize the vectors to mean 0, std 1 before further processing the data. If I would have dealt with an image, I could use torchvision.transforms:
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
    import torch

    data_2d = torch.rand(1, 100,100)
    normalized_data_2d = transforms.Normalize(mean = (data_2d.mean(),), std = (data_2d.std(),))(data_2d)
    print(f'mean: {normalized_data_2d.mean()} ~ 0 , std: {normalized_data_2d.std()} ~ 1, ok')

I get:
mean: -4.1373571235681084e-08 ~ 0 , std: 0.9999999403953552 ~ 1, ok
When I use 1d data in the same manner:
    data_1d = torch.rand(100)
    normalized_data_1d = transforms.Normalize(mean = (data_1d.mean(),), std = (data_1d.std(),))(data_1d)

I get TypeError: Tensor is not a torch image error:
Is there an elegant way to standardize 1d vectors using torch transform?

You could use atleast_3d to make the input tensor the expected shape and afterwards squeeze out the singleton dimensions to make it 1d again, e.g.,
normalized_data_1d = Normalize(
    mean=(data_1d.mean(),),
    std=(data_1d.std(),)
)(
    torch.atleast_3d(data_1d)  # make shape "at least 3d"
).squeeze()  # squeeze out singleton dimensions

Or, equivalently:
normalized_data_1d = Normalize(
    mean=(data_1d.mean(),),
    std=(data_1d.std(),)
)(
    data_1d[None, :, None]  # make shape 3d
).flatten()  # flatten output

